# filter an array of objects based on specifc attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array of displayed columns :

```
displayedColumns = ['CompanyName','Ticker', 'Id', 'Name', 'Date', 
      'Spot', 'PreviousTradeDate', 'PreviousSpot', 'FPrice', 'Status']
```

and an array of objects (retrieved from db,which contains more than the displayed columns attributes  ) :

```
 data = [ {CompanyName = "..." Ticker = "..." other attributes........}
{.......} ]
```

I am having trouble with filtering the `data` array to show only the `displayed columns` attributes and their values (without the other attributes)

didn't quite understand how to do it with `map()` function when I want to filter by more than one value

thanks a lot

Comment: To clarify - you want to iterate over each object in `data` and filter out any keys that aren't listed in `displayedColumns`?

Comment: basically yes, but I was hoping to find a solution that does not include loops

Comment: what about wanted properties which are not in data's objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the keys for each object in the `data` array and check if those key exists in the `displayedColumns` or not. Below is the illustration of how you can do this:

```js
var displayedColumns = ['CompanyName','Ticker', 'Id', 'Name', 'Date', 
      'Spot', 'PreviousTradeDate', 'PreviousSpot', 'FPrice', 'Status'];
      
var data = [
    {
      'CompanyName': 'CompanyName1',
      'Ticker': 'Ticker1',
      'SomeRandomProperty': 'SomeRandomProperty1'
    },
    {
      'CompanyName': 'CompanyName2',
      'Ticker': 'Ticker2',
      'SomeRandomProperty': 'SomeRandomProperty2',
      'Name': 'Name1'
    },
    {
      'CompanyName': 'CompanyName3',
      'Ticker': 'Ticker3',
      'SomeRandomProperty': 'SomeRandomProperty3',
      'Name': 'Name3',
      'FPrice':'FPrice1',
      'testProperty': 'testProperty1'
    }
];
var finalObj = [];
data.forEach((obj)=>{
   var keys = Object.keys(obj);
   var innerObj = {};
   keys.forEach((key)=>{
     if(displayedColumns.indexOf(key) !== -1){
       innerObj[key] = obj[key];
     }
   });
   finalObj.push(innerObj);
});

console.log(finalObj);
```

> If you are also concerned to make this code work in IE browser then don't use `includes()` as it do not work in IE and also change the arrow function to normal functions.

Answer (score 3):

You could map the array with new object with only the wanted keys.

```js
var displayedColumns = ['CompanyName','Ticker', 'Id'],
    data = [{ CompanyName: 'ABC', Ticker: '123', Id: 1, x: 'foo' }, { CompanyName: 'ABD', Ticker: '124', Id: 2, x: 'bar' }];
    result = data.map(o => Object.assign(...displayedColumns.map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] }))));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This will give you `undefined` value for the keys that are not present in `data`. Let's say objects in `data` array do not have `Ticker` property then it will set that property and set it's value to `undefined`

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal, i think op wants a sub set of the properties.

Comment: OP wants to remove the extraneous property from `data` and if there is no all the properties from `displayedColumns` array then above code will set those properties in `result` array as `undefined`

Comment: @NinaScholz 
thanks a lot, but this returns an empty array for some reason

Comment: @Jonathan, please add some `data` to the question.

Comment: I need the end result to be : 
[{CompanyName : " .." Ticker : "" Id : ".. "  ....... Status: ".."},
{CompanyName : " .." Ticker : "" Id : ".. "  ....... Status: ".."},
{CompanyName : " .." Ticker : "" Id : ".. "  ....... Status: ".."},
{CompanyName : " .." Ticker : "" Id : ".. "  ....... Status: ".."}, and so on..]

based of the values that each row in 'data' has for those attributes